# TGB 202 Classic

Tags: motorcycle

Where does the air duct pipe fit? I have fitted it to the air cleaner, the other end is fitted to an elbow but I can’t find anywhere to fit that! The elbow is part number 420078, on the fische it is refered to as PIPE COMP..INTAKE

Comment: Some photos, but an educated guess will be the carburettor..

Comment: Yeah, since there may not be someone with the exact same model, you may need to add pictures all around the areas it might lead to.  Or you might include more diagrams such as the fiche you mention.